# Moving from Dev to Prod System

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, heroku, amazon-ec2, redis

I've been using Heroku/Nodejitsu coupled with MongoHQ while developing my application (a Node/Express + Redis + MongoDB API for an iPhone app). It's time to move to production.

I don't want to learn linux sysadmin - so I'd love to just stick with this setup... however, my app is 100% dependent on database I/O... so I need the absolute fastest connection possible here.

Is there any way to get "local" speed this way? I certainly don't want to cross the public internet to do I/O with my database. Any suggestions or recommendations? Do I just need to move it all to Amazon/Google/SoftLayer?

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

If you want speed then move it all to the same system. Google has a SQL database available to your app. It all comes pre-setup, you don't need to learn Linux, or do any setup (if you don't want to). It would be as close to local speed as you could get.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/